# Regarding integrals in Sec 3.14. of Titchmarsh's book

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

In Section 3.14. of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*, there is a sentence that I could not understand (Red-underlined sentence in [here](https://imgur.com/a/WcdpnLv)):

Question 1 - How does $\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C \log \dfrac{1}{w} \dfrac{x^w}{w} dw = - \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \Delta_C \log^2 w$ hold? I had studied $\Delta_C$ and its relation to $Z - P$ (the number of zeros of a meromorphic function inside the curve minus number of its poles) from Churchill's book *Complex Variables and Applications* and I reviewed it now. I also searched the Web and the books I had for quite a while before posting this question but nothing I found to help me understanding this equality. Introducing texts, lecture notes or the like for understanding this will be of much help.

Question 2 - The same of mentioned sentence finishes with the claim that the term is equal to $$\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C \log \dfrac{1}{w} \dfrac{x^w -1}{w} dw - \log \delta.$$ How this conclusion is derived?

Comment: If you accept my other two answers I can answer this one as well :)

Comment: @eulersgroupie, thank you very much for your answers. Let me few hours I will study them and I will reply to them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\Delta_C \log^2 w$ here means the same thing as $\log^2 w\big\vert_{\delta e^{-i\pi}}^{\delta e^{i\pi}}$ which is commonly used in real analysis, for example $\int_a^b x dx=\frac{x^2}{2}\big\vert_a^b$ (remember the fundamental theorem of calculus analog holds for holomorphic functions but one has to be careful with the choice of paths/which branch of the antiderivative to pick in case the antiderivative is "multivalued". Which branch must be chosen above is indicated by the $\delta e^{i\pi}$ and $\delta e^{-i\pi}$, one has argument $\pi$ the other $-\pi$).
2. $$\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C  \dfrac{x^w -1}{w} \log \dfrac{1}{w}dw - \log \delta=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C  \dfrac{x^w -1}{w}\log \dfrac{1}{w} dw +\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C  \dfrac{1}{w} \log \dfrac{1}{w}dw =$$ $$\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C  \dfrac{x^w}{w} \log \dfrac{1}{w}dw$$
   since
   $$\dfrac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_C  \dfrac{1}{w}\log \dfrac{1}{w} dw=-\log\delta.$$

Comment: For Q1, I mean how to prove $\int_C \dfrac{1}{w} \log \dfrac{1}{w} dw = -\dfrac{1}{2} \Delta_C \log^2 w$?

Comment: @Ali That's the chain rule, write $u=\log w$ and use $\log\frac{1}{w}=-\log w$ and $du=\frac{1}{w}dw$.